# SVN svn:ignore Not Working When Directory Contains Versioned Files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, nuget

I have a situation here that I cannot seem to work out.

For various issues and compatibility problems outside of my control I've had to add a couple of files from within my ASP.NET packages directory.  Horrid I know but there is no other work around currently.

On my SVN root I currently have setup an ignore rule as:

```
svn:ignore packages
```

However the entire contents of the packages directory is still shown in the SVN add dialog.

I've also tried:

```
packages .
*.packages
*.packages .
*.packages*
*packages*
```

None of the configurations I've tried have worked.  I'm now suspecting that SVN is ignoring the ignore property because there is a version controlled child object in the packages directory.

Is this expected behaviour and is there a way to ignore the non-version stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have some child entries of the packages directory in source control then, by definition, you *also* have the packages directory itself already in source control. `svn:ignore` works *only* on the svn `add` operation, i.e. during the process of adding items *not* under source control. Thus, `svn:ignore` can have no effect on the already-versioned packages directory.

So the limitation (if you want to call it that) of `svn:ignore` is what is causing you an issue. Your solution, ironically enough, is to turn that same limitation into a benefit, to wit: Add an `svn:ignore` property on the packages directory itself (not the parent as you have been trying to do) with the value of just an asterisk (*). That will then ignore any children of packages *except* for those already versioned which you want to have there.